# Cannot insert entity with null foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Idea: Key entity, that can be replaced by other key, if that happens they get their FK's pointing to each other.

```
public class Key {
    string Id;
    string ReplacesId;
    Key Replaces;
    string ReplacedById;
    Key ReplacedBy;
}
```

Fluent mapping

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Key>().HasOne(k => k.Replaces)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Key>(k => k.ReplacesId)
    .IsRequired(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<NagKey>().HasOne(k => k.ReplacedBy)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<NagKey>(k => k.ReplacedById)
    .IsRequired(false);
```

Problem: Trying to save an entity, it fails with duplicate foreign key error (which is null) as follows:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Keys' with unique index 'IX_Keys_ReplacedById'. The duplicate key value is (). The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by making indexes not unique:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Key>()
    .HasIndex(x => x.ReplacedById)
    .IsUnique(false)
    .HasFilter(null);

modelBuilder.Entity<Key>()
    .HasIndex(x => x.ReplacesId)
    .IsUnique(false)
    .HasFilter(null);
```